# How to create and use a map of priority queues with a custom comparator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, priority-queue

For context, I would like to create an "order backlog" where I have a map of string keys(symbol) and the value would be a priority queue, which contains all the orders for that symbol in a prioritized manner.

My custom comparator, which takes in a boolean since buy orders and sell orders have the oppposite prioritization:

```
struct Compare{
    bool buySide;
    Compare(bool side) : buySide(side) {}
    bool operator()(pair<int, float> order1, pair<int, float> order2) {
        if (buySide) {
            return order1.second < order2.second;
        }
        return order1.second > order2.second;
    };
};
```

I'm trying to create a map like so:

```
typedef priority_queue<pair<int, float>, vector<pair<int, float>>, Compare> priorityQueue;
map<string, priorityQueue> marketBuys;
```

and then using it like so:

```
if (marketBuys.find(order.symbol) == marketBuys.end()) {
    marketBuys[order.symbol] = priorityQueue(Compare(true));
}
marketBuys[order.symbol].push(make_pair(order.orderId, order.price));
```

However, I don't think I'm creating the priority queue correctly, and the important part is I need to somehow instantiate the priority queue with the correct prioritization, so I have to use the comparator constructor. I'm getting errors like

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, float>, std::vector<std::pair<int, float> >, Compare>::priority_queue()’
```

If I just wanted a standalone priority queue, I would create it like so:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, float>, vector<pair<int, float>>, Compare> priorityQueue(Compare(true));
```

But I can't figure out how to put those inside maps. I also tried:

```
if (marketBuys.find(order.symbol) == marketBuys.end()) {
    priorityQueue pq(Compare(true));
    marketBuys[order.symbol] = pq;
}
marketBuys[order.symbol].push(make_pair(order.orderId, order.price));
```

which also didn't work.

Comment: ChatGPT just told me: The issue you're facing arises from the fact that std::map requires that the mapped type (i.e., the priorityQueue) must be default-constructible.
If this is true, then the simplest solution is I should just create 2 different custom comparators so they don't need to use a boolean constructor?

Comment: it also said: you can use a std::map with std::unique_ptr as the mapped type, so you can dynamically allocate the priorityQueue objects with the desired comparator. Is this true? ChatGPT usually just talks out of its ass so I don't really trust it

Comment: side topic: if you are trying to learn HFT this is not how you should store buys.

Comment: why not? this is just one of the data structures being used. Everything gets cross referenced with another map that actually holds order information and is the authority

Comment: the structure is too slow for any practical use in real time trading

Comment: how should I store the orders then?

Comment: anyways, your issue is because the [] operator creates the (default-)object before assigning your rvalue to it. ChatGPT is trying to wrap an unique_ptr to make null a viable default value, pretty generic response. Design wise, I would suggest templating the side, which might be viable for your use case -- You are naming your variable as "marketBuys" you should know its buyside at compile time.

Comment: in trading world we typically store it in unordered_map or any O(1) hash maps.

Comment: Make it `marketBuys.emplace(order.symbol, priorityQueue(Compare(true)));` This will solve the immediate issue.

Comment: oh ya I know unordered_map is faster, and saves O(logn) time compared to map. I'm only using an ordered map here because of a unique constraint of ordering the symbols in alphabetical order, which is probably unneeded in the real world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::map<>::operator[]` need the objet to be default constructible. Here you can't use this operator. Other `map` functions are accessible.

```cpp
   auto fd = marketBuys.find(order.symbol);
   if ( fd == marketBuys.end() ) {
      fd = marketBuys.emplace(order.symbol, priorityQueue(Compare(true))).first;
   }
   fd->second.push(std::make_pair(order.orderId, order.price));
```